# When the standard methods of testing convergence don't work

Tags: analysis

For instance, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$ is convergent,but which are the possible and most common methods for proving such series(for which we can't use d'Alembert's and Cauchy's methods for example).

Comment: In this case partial fractions and a telescoping sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a decent summary of convergence tests [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests).

Your series is shown to be convergent by the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Integral_test), since

$$\int_1^\infty \frac 1{(x+1)(x+2)}\,dx=\ln\left( \frac 32 \right)$$

Your series is shown to be convergent by the [direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Direct_comparison_test), since it each term is less than $\frac 1{n^2}$ and [we know that series converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) to $\frac{\pi^2}6$.

The Wikipedia page does not cover [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), which as @MarkBennet observes includes your series, since

$$\frac 1{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac 1{n+1}-\frac 1{n+2}$$

So your series equals

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac 1{1+1}-\frac 1{n+2}\right)=\frac 12$$

The [limit of the summand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_of_the_summand), [ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Ratio_test), and [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Root_test) tests are all inconclusive.

Do you need more?

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your specific example, it holds:

$$\frac 1{(n+1)(n+2)}< \frac1{n^2}$$
and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{n^2 }$ is convergent.

Just a comparison test.